# Styling Items based on group sizes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am fairly new to WPF so forgive me if I am missing something obvious. I'm having a problem where I have a collection of AggregatedLabels and I am trying to bind the ItemCount of each AggregatedLabel to the FontSize in my DataTemplate so that if the ItemCount of an AggregatedLabel is large then a larger fontSize will be displayed in my listBox etc. The part that I am struggling with is the binding to the ValueConverter. Can anyone assist? Many thanks!

**XAML Snippet**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TagsTemplate">
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=Default}" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            FontSize="{Binding ItemCount, 
                Converter={StaticResource CountToFontSizeConverter}, 
                Mode=Default}" 
            Foreground="#FF0D0AF7"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox x:Name="tagsList" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AggregatedLabels, Mode=Default}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TagsTemplate}" 
    Style="{StaticResource tagsStyle}" 
    Margin="200,10,16.171,11.88" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your `CollectionView` in place you might be able to bind to the `Groups` property, i've never used that, will try it and clarify if possible...

**Edit:** Allright, here's one way to do it:

The data you bind to **needs to be the `CollectionView.Groups`**, the `CollectionView` should be defined like this:

```
CollectionView view = (ListCollectionView) CollectionViewSource.
    GetDefaultView(LabelData);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Name"));
```

Then you can bind to the respective properties of [`CollectionViewGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.aspx) in code, what you need are probably:

1. `ItemCount`
2. `Name`

That being said your original binding should work.

Note: You only pass one value to the converter, the ItemCount, thus it should look like this:

```
public class CountToFontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        const int minFontSize = 6;
        const int maxFontSize = 38;
        const int increment = 3;

        if ((minFontSize + (int)value + increment) < maxFontSize)
        {
            return (double)(minFontSize + (int)value + increment);
        }
        return (double)maxFontSize;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Edit:** Further clarifications...

Just add the `CollectionView` to your `ViewModel` as a property and create it in its constructor:

```
public class TagCloudViewModel//:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabelModel> AggregatedLabels 
        {get; set;}
    public CollectionView AggregatedLabelsView {get; set;} // <-This...

    public TagCloudViewModel()
    {
        var data = new DataAccess();
        AggregatedLabels = data.GetData();

        //...and this:
        AggregatedLabelsView  = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.
            GetDefaultView(AggregatedLabels);
        AggregatedLabelsView.GroupDescriptions.Add(
            new PropertyGroupDescription("Name"));
    }
}
```

Then bind to `AggregatedLabelsView.Groups`.

Comment: I have done that, this is just a snippet of my XAML - sorry I didn't clarify.

Comment: I am aggregating my labels using the "AgrregateLabel Collection Code" above and I just want to bind the Count of all the Items in each AggregatedLabel to the FontSize if that makes sense?

Comment: It does make sense, but does your `AggregatedLabelModel` have a public property named `ItemCount`? Also i've added a link to a guide on binding debugging to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have pasted the class that I am binding to. How would I add a public property for ItemCount - I believe this is the problem?

Comment: If the code you posted is the complete class how is there anything which would indicate a count? I'm quite confused how content (or whatever should be indicated by the font size) should be derived from that class.

Comment: Ok apologies I think I misunderstood and thought ItemCount was a method for every collection. How would I fix this problem?

Comment: What collection are you referring to? If you mean the parent collection that would end up giving you the same value for every item, so where are the children that should belong to your items? I have no idea how to fix this unless you can tell me where the `ItemCount` was supposed to come from.

Comment: Ok so I think the way it was supposed to work is using a CollectionView and then binding to the ItemCount of the child collection does this make more sense?

Comment: @Ben: Do you want the FontSize to be sized according to the number of items in AggregatedLabels? So if you add 10 AggregatedLabelModel to the collection, the number you'd want to end up in the converter is 10. Is that correct?

Comment: ...why would you want to set this at Item-level if it applies to **all** items???

Comment: +1, I don't think this answer deserved to be downvoted as it was pretty hard to understand what you really were asking.

Comment: @H.B.: I didn't downvote you, I upvoted you after you got the downvote

Comment: Sorry my question is not very clear. So if you look at my last code snippet I would like to do something like this. Group the AgrregatedLabels together by name and then for each group bind that count to my IvalueConverter, really sorry if it's not clear.

Comment: @Meleak: That was not referring to know, i know you wouldn't do that :) Just put it there to whoever wrote it.

Comment: @Ben: Very much so. I've added a stub to the answer, will have to play around with `CollectionView`, can't tell you anything right now since i haven't used it before.

Comment: Thank you I really appreaciate your help :)

Comment: Updated answer, hope that works (did for me at least) Edit: You need to change the value converter to take a single input though! It's just the ItemCount which gets passed.

Comment: @Meleak: You seem to have a hard time today (or with this rather), deleting your answer twice; thank you for the upvote, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @H.B.: Yes yes, as the answer said.. I didn't like it very much :) The first answer was deleted because I "missunderstood" the question, so it didn't really answer it. I'm trying your approach now but I'm out of luck. Not sure how the binding to the ItemCount should look as I can't see how it fits with the DataContext

Comment: @Meleak: e.g. in the DataTemplate: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToFontSizeConverter}}"/>` it's important to bind directly to the CollectionView (which needs to be at least of the subtype `ListCollectionView`)

Comment: Thanks alot H.B great answer - with regards to the CollectionView how do I actually declare the binding? tagsList.ItemsSource = View.Groups;? I'm trying to avoid code behind.

Comment: @Ben: Then you should expose the view as a public property, make sure to bind to the view *not* its groups. (ie. if `DataView` is your `CollectionView` you use `ItemsSource="{Binding DataView, Converter...}"`)

Comment: Sorry a little bit confused - have added my View and ViewModel to the code can you assist?

Comment: @Ban: You're really hopeless... Updated my answer.

Comment: @H.B: Ah I think I got it, the property ItemCount in the Binding is actually a dependency property in AggregatedLabelModel which in turn is binding to the correct CollectionViewGroup by Name?

Comment: @Meleak: Err, no, `ItemCount` comes from `CollectionViewGroup` and is calculated from the items which share the same value for the property; the `Name` is also from `CollectionViewGroup` and is generated dynamically, it takes the value of the shared value of all the items in the group. e.g. if i group on `Occupation` one group might have an `ItemCount` of 3 and the name `Programmer` if i have three people whose value for `Occupation` is `Programmer`.

Comment: @H.B: .... It appears I still missunderstood the question... That's three in a row :) Thought that e.g. 3 items with the same Name, should be represented with 3 items in the `ListBox` but of course they should just be represented with one post so now I see why the Bindings work. Arghh...

Comment: @Ben & Meleak: Woops, sorry, i've been talking shit, you *do* bind to the groups, my concentration in the middle of night is not the best. I've probably wasted quite some time of yours there (especially yours Meleak, since i think i'm more than even with Ben :P)

Comment: @HB thanks for your help, GroupDescription doesnt seem to group by "Name" instead its arranging by "Name" and therefore the Converter is not activated... Nightmare

Comment: That certainly took a while, glad it's over honestly :D

Comment: Im sure you enjoyed the journey :)

Comment: Well, at the very least i now know the basics of how to group items, which is something that surely will be useful.